# Struts unterminated string constant error calling JS function

Tags: javascript, struts2, struts

I am trying to call a JS function from within Struts:

```
<s:iterator value="%{foo}" status="stat">
    <a id="idname" href="#" onClick="javascript:getValue('<s:property value="news"/>');    return false;"><s:property value="newsName" /></a>
</s:iterator>
```

When I do so I get an unterminated string constant error. However when I use the escaped values that I have for:

When I use the literal value of the "news" variable:

```
<s:iterator value="%{foo}" status="stat">
  <a id="idname" href="#" onClick="javascript:getValue('http:&#47;&#47;www.cnn.com&#47;2013&#47;01&#47;10&#47;travel&#47;flight-movie-united-232&#47;index.html?iref=obnetwork');return false;">        
  <s:property value="newsName" /></a>
</s:iterator>
```

No such error is thrown.

The value of:

```
<s:property value="news"/>
```

is the string:

```
http:&#47;&#47;www.cnn.com&#47;2013&#47;01&#47;10&#47;travel&#47;flight-movie-united-232&#47;index.html?iref=obnetwork
```

I have checked this by outputting it to the page.

And, no, I don't have to escape the property itself; this works:

```
<a id="idname" href="#" onClick="javascript:getValue('http://www.blah.com/<s:property value="otherValue"/>');return false;"><s:property value="userName" /></a>
```

Comment: I do not get this error with the news value you provide; you may need to provide more information. Are you sure that's the particular item that causes the error? IMO you should always JS-escape anything you want to use as a JS string.

Comment: Dave- the value that I am providing *is* a JS escaped string. It's a URL with the &#47; as opposed to \

Comment: I see what the specific example is. I also don't know how how it's being generated/etc, so *I* have no knowledge about its suitability. What I'm saying is that given the example you provide, I don't get the error.

Comment: the response is coming back from a Java call. Not sure what other info you need.

Comment: Anything. As I said, I cannot reproduce the problem with the example you're providing: with the URL exposed as an action property, using the link tag cut-and-pasted, I get no error, and it works as expected.

Comment: That's what is driving me nuts. I can put in any of the random values that I get - all of them work when I hard-code them in.

:(

Comment: Create an SSCCE that demonstrates the failure and put it on github or something. Without knowing what precisely you're doing it's going to be difficult to help since I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem.

Look at the source below: find what's different (at a functional level) and you'll likely find the error. (For the most part, cut-and-pasted from a live app, though I hand-edited some names.)

**Foo.java**, to hold the data:

```java
public class Foo {
    private String news;
    private String newsName;
    // Plus public getters and a ctor to init.
}
```

**AnAction.java**, creates and exposes list:

```java
public class AnAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<Foo> foo; // Plus public getter.

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        foo = Arrays.asList(new Foo("http:&#47;&#47;www.cnn.com&#47;2013&#47;01&#47;10&#47;travel&#47;flight-movie-united-232&#47;index.html?iref=obnetwork", "YOOOOOO!"));
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**struts.xml**, configuration:

```xml
<action name="a" class="test.AnAction">
  <result>/WEB-INF/jsps/a.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**a.jsp**, view layer:

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<html>
  <body>
    <s:iterator value="%{foo}" status="stat">
      <a id="idname" href="#" onClick="getValue('<s:property value="news"/>'); return false;"><s:property value="newsName" /></a>
    </s:iterator>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dave - thanks so much for your help. I'm just the front end guy, I've looked over the Java code and nothing stands out. I'll update you after I know more.